# A Twist Of The Unexpected

Tags: idioms, metaphors

In this [sentence](https://ca.sports.yahoo.com/news/2018-world-cup-will-have-its-own-extreme-site-234853806.html):

> In four years the grandest soccer tournament of all will ***take another twist of the unexpected***, as Russia welcomes the travelling World Cup hordes with open arms – and promptly packs a bunch of them off to somewhere that is usually so cold most people assume it is in Siberia.

Does "a twist of the unexpected" mean "a twist of the unexpected ***kind***"?

Comment: I think "taking a twist of the unexpected" is analogous to "taking a twist of lime" and adding it to a cocktail.  "The unexpected" is a noun that metaphorically "adds a weird taste", much like a lime.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, it would be equivalent to saying "In four years the grandest soccer tournament of all will take another unexpected twist."

(You could technically say "a twist of the unexpected kind," but it would sound odd because it is overly complicated)

Comment: Does that I could write "an accident of the unexpected" and "a cat of the unexpected", even though appending "kind" or "type" to these two phrases would make them sound better?

Comment: @meatie I would not write either phrase without also using _kind_ or _type._ One must understand that an _unexpected twist_ is common expression in English (for example, it is usually considered a necessary component of a good mystery story), so _twist of an unexpected_ needs no explanation to a native speaker. But _unexpected cat_ and even _unexpected accident_ are not a fixed phrases, and so your two proposals not only sound better with type or kind, but also demand some such word.

Comment: @meatie As CarSmack said, an "unexpected twist" is a English expression. It likely comes from a similar expression: "an unexpected turn of events," where "turn of events" replaces "twist."

Answer (score 0):

As written, it's really a tautology, presumably to add emphasis to the *unexpectedness* of the event.

> [twist [noun]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twist): an unexpected or strange occurrence.

It could have been written with exactly the same meaning as *"... the grandest soccer tournament of all will take another twist,"* or *"... the grandest soccer tournament of all will have another instance of the unexpected,"*.

Although it technically means the same thing, I **wouldn't** say *"A twist of the unexpected kind"* because it implies there is a kind of twist that is **not** unexpected.

---

#### Edit:

There also seems be some confusion because of the different uses of the word *"unexpected"*. Take notice of the article *"the"*, meaning it's a noun here, not an adjective!

```
... of the unexpected.
        ^     ^
   article    noun

... of the unexpected kind.
        ^       ^       ^
   article  adjective  noun
```

"The unexpected" **(N)** means the collection of all things which are unexpected **(A)**.

When something from such a collection happens, we can refer to it as "a case of X".

Don't confuse this with the adjective as in "an unexpected accident" or "an accident of the unexpected kind".

Comment: Like the twist in my vodka rocks...

Comment: Does that mean I could write "an accident of the unexpected" and "a cat of the unexpected", even though appending "kind" or "type" to these two phrases would make them sound better?

Comment: I don't know what you mean at all by "a cat of the unexpected". I've added an edit about "an accident of the unexpected kind", which is a technically correct but awkward way of saying "an unexpected accident". "an accident of the unexpected" would **not** be correct.

Comment: Why is "a twist of the unexpected" okay, but not "an accident of the unexpected"?

Comment: @meatie, That's an excellent question. I think you should post as another question to make it a first rate question rather than a comment.  Also include "a cat of the unexpected" for fun.  You'll get a very good response I think.

Answer (score 0):

We say, an "unexpected twist."

To say, "a twist of the unexpected" might just be a clever turn of phrase (like for a TV cooking show, the host might be making a play on words regarding the "twist of lemon" used in recipe speech.

(But then, we must remember that sports writers' styles and language contusions are often the butt of jokes!) Long live the sports writers' colourful english!